# how to write multiple iferror statements with and statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to wrap each formula with an IFERROR statement for my nested formula below. I reviewed other sources and found that this can be done with a comma between the two. I believe what is throwing me off is that I have the `& " "` between each if statement (which I need to keep).

Below is my original formula and my latest formula with what I have tried. The formula is not taking. I am unsure how to do this properly. What am I doing wrong?

Original formula

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$11,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($U9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$15,$U9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$15,$AB9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$10,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($M9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$9,$M9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$9,$Z9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$9,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($AH9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$16,$AH9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$16,$AE9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$16,"")
,"error"))
```

New formula

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$11,"")
,"Error MUC Video")),
& " "
IFERROR(
& IF(AND($U9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$15,$U9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$15,$AB9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$10,"")
,"Error SMR Video"))
& " "
& IF(AND($M9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$9,$M9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$9,$Z9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$9,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($AH9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$16,$AH9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$16,$AE9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$16,"")
```

Comment: I don't want to test the whole thing and post as an answer but it looks like the `IFERROR(` should go between `&` and `IF` instead of before the `&`, which is what you have now.

Comment: @EngineerToast I just tried this and it didn't work. `IFERROR(
IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$11,"")
,"Error MUC Video")),
IFERROR(
& " "
& IF(AND($U9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$15,$U9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$15,$AB9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$10,"")
,"Error SMR Video"))`

Comment: new formula first `&` is misplaced, should be after the white space (or white space and & not needed), second `IFERROR` seems to be missing what to do if the error condition is met.

Comment: @gns100 I'm trying to follow but cannot figure out what you are saying. Can you show it by chance?

Comment: I see your second nested error condition. so just get rid of the first `&` (can't start with an `&`). This comment incorporates @EngineerToast comment about moving the `IFERROR(`.

Comment: OK, taking a step back, are you trying to nest your `IFERROR` or just trying to add one to each `IF`? Also, what error condition are you trying to "gracefully" exit from? If there is no "real" excel error, then you don't want the `IFERROR`

Comment: @gns100 I am trying to add an `IFERROR` to each `IF` condition. The reason so I can troubleshoot which condition is throwing an error. This is the latest one I've tried (this is a snippet of the second if and iferror) .... `& " " IFERROR(IF(AND(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large, messy formula that's formatted in a way to make it more legible. I'm going to start by making it way shorter so it's easier to follow. First, let's get rid of all the big AND statements:

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(AND(a1,a2,a3,a4),a99,"")
& " "
& IF(AND(b1,b2,b3,b4),b99,"")
& " "
& IF(AND(c1,c2,c3),c99,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($d1,d2,d3),d99,"")
,"error"))
```

Actually, let's remove them entirely. We'll just use a single stand-in for the AND formulas:

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(a1,a99,"")
& " "
& IF(b1,b99,"")
& " "
& IF(c1,c99,"")
& " "
& IF(d1,d99,"")
,"error"))
```

We can follow that much more easily now. TRIM will remove spaces and IFERROR catches errors. What's inside IFERROR? It's a concatenation of several strings:

```
IF(a1,a99,"") & " " & IF(b1,b99,"") & " " & IF(c1,c99,"") & " " & IF(d1,d99,"")
```

You see how each IF has a space between it? You can combine strings by just putting an ampersand `&` between them. In this case, the strings are whatever the IF returns and the spaces `" "`.

Now, say you want to wrap one of those IF in an IFERROR. Let's look at how you have it in your question, again with a little simplification in place:

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(AND(a1,a2,a3,a4),a99,"")
,"Error MUC Video")),
& " "
IFERROR(
& IF(AND(b1,b2,b3,b4),b99,"")
,"Error SMR Video"))
& " "
& IF(AND(c1,c2,c3),c99,"")
& " "
& IF(AND($d1,d2,d3),d99,"")
```

I can already tell the parentheses `( )` are messed up somewhere because you only have 1 at the very end. Let's ignore that for now and just work on the IFERROR part. We can simplify it further like we did above.

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(
IF(a1,a99,"")
,"Error MUC Video")),
& " "
IFERROR(
& IF(b1,b99,"")
,"Error SMR Video"))
& " "
& IF(c1,c99,"")
& " "
& IF(d1,d99,"")
```

That's still a little hard to read.  What if we formatted it like this:

```
=TRIM(
      IFERROR(
              IF(a1,a99,""),"Error MUC Video"
             )
     ),
 & " "
 IFERROR(
         & IF(b1,b99,""),"Error SMR Video"
        )
 )
 & " "
 & IF(c1,c99,"")
 & " "
 & IF(d1,d99,"")
```

The parentheses after the first IFERROR closes the TRIM function.
The second IFERROR has the ampersand `&` *inside* the function. It should be before it.
The parentheses after the second IFERROR doesn't match any opening parentheses.
The comma after the closing parentheses shouldn't be there, either.
It's missing a closing parentheses for the TRIM function.
The formula should look more like this:

```
TRIM( IFERROR() & " " & IFERROR() & " " & IF() & " " & IF() )
```

Taking all that into consideration, I think your finally formula would best for you if it was formatted like this this:

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$11,""),"Error MUC Video")
& " " & 
IFERROR(IF(AND($U9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$15,$U9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$15,$AB9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$10,""),"Error SMR Video")
& " " & 
IF(AND($M9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$9,$M9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$9,$Z9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$9,"")
& " " & 
IF(AND($AH9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$16,$AH9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$16,$AE9<>"Complete"),Key!$L$16,"")
)
```

If you want to wrap the last two IF statements in their own IFERROR, I would format it the same way as with the first two. Keep each piece on its own line.

---

The next time you have an issue like this with a  big formula, try cutting it way down like I did above so you can more easily spot the error.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer I've received on this board. Very informative and I learned a lot!